# How to create a vector of all decorated functions from a specific module?

Tags: module, rust, decorator

I have a file `main.rs` and a file `rule.rs`. I want to define functions in `rule.rs` to be included in the `Rules::rule` vector without having to push them one by one. I'd prefer a loop to push them.

**main.rs**:

```
struct Rules {
    rule: Vec<fn(arg: &Arg) -> bool>,
}

impl Rules {
    fn validate_incomplete(self, arg: &Arg) -> bool {
        // iterate through all constraints and evaluate, if false return and stop
        for constraint in self.incomplete_rule_constraints.iter() {
            if !constraint(&arg) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    }
}
```

**rule.rs**:

```
pub fn test_constraint1(arg: &Arg) -> bool {
    arg.last_element().total() < 29500
}

pub fn test_constraint2(arg: &Arg) -> bool {
    arg.last_element().total() < 35000
}
```

`Rules::rule` should be populated with `test_constraint1` and `test_constraint2`.

In Python, I could add a decorator `@rule_decorator` above the constraints which you want to be included in the `Vec`, but I don't see an equivalent in Rust.

In Python, I could use `dir(module)` to see all available methods/attributes.

Python variant:

```py
class Rules:

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.rule = []

        for member in dir(self):
            method = getattr(self, member)
            if "rule_decorator" in dir(method):
                self.rule.append(method)

    def validate_incomplete(self, arg: Arg):
        for constraint in self.incomplete_rule_constraints:
            if not constraint(arg):
                return False
        return True
```

With the rule.py file:

```py
@rule_decorator
def test_constraint1(arg: Arg):
    return arg.last_element().total() < 29500

@rule_decorator
def test_constraint1(arg: Arg):
    return arg.last_element().total() < 35000
```

All functions with a `rule_decorator` are added to the `self.rule` list and checked off by the `validate_incomplete` function.

Comment: Hi there! Unfortunately, I am really confused by your question. So you want to add function pointers to a `Vec`, ok. You don't want to push them one by one (why?), but via a loop, ok. Why don't you use a loop then? What has all of this to do with decorators? Also: please provide a [MCVE] (particularly, we have no idea what `Arg` is. Also: `validate_incomplete`, the `Rules` wrapper and the different modules seem completely irrelevant to the main question). Could you try to explain your problem differently/with more detail?

Comment: If i would use a loop, how would the loop know which functions to select from the rule.rs file if I can't give them a decorator? I do not wan't to push them line by line with .push, because there would be more than 20...

Comment: This is precisely what the `#[test]` annotations for the test-suite do, but they are special cased in the compiler, and while a generalization was proposed for custom test frameworks, it is still constrained to test suites.

Comment: See also [How to introspect all available methods & members in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39266001/155423); [How can I statically register structures at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32678845/155423); [How can I provide a custom test attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50786312/155423);

Answer (score 2):

You can, with some tweaks and restrictions, achieve your goals. You'll need to use the [inventory crate](https://crates.io/crates/inventory). This is **limited to Linux, macOS and Windows** at the moment.

You can then use `inventory::submit` to add values to a global registry, `inventory::collect` to build the registry, and `inventory::iter` to iterate over the registry.

Due to language restrictions, you cannot create a registry for values of a type that you do not own, which includes the raw function pointer. We will need to create a *newtype* called `Predicate` to use the crate:

```
use inventory; // 0.1.3

struct Predicate(fn(&u32) -> bool);
inventory::collect!(Predicate);

struct Rules;

impl Rules {
    fn validate_incomplete(&self, arg: &u32) -> bool {
        inventory::iter::<Predicate>
            .into_iter()
            .all(|Predicate(constraint)| constraint(arg))
    }
}

mod rules {
    use super::Predicate;

    pub fn test_constraint1(arg: &u32) -> bool {
        *arg < 29500
    }
    inventory::submit!(Predicate(test_constraint1));

    pub fn test_constraint2(arg: &u32) -> bool {
        *arg < 35000
    }
    inventory::submit!(Predicate(test_constraint2));
}

fn main() {
    if Rules.validate_incomplete(&42) {
        println!("valid");
    } else {
        println!("invalid");
    }
}
```

There are a few more steps you'd need to take to reach your originally-stated goal:

- "a vector"

  You can `collect` from the provided iterator to build a `Vec`.
- "decorated functions"

  You can write your own procedural macro that will call `inventory::submit!(Predicate(my_function_name));` for you.
- "from a specific module"

  You can add [the module name](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.module_path.html) into the `Predicate` struct and filter on that later.

See also:

- [How can I statically register structures at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32678845/155423)

Answer (score 1):

Rust does not have the same reflection features as Python. In particular, you cannot iterate through all functions of a module at runtime. At least you can't do that with builtin tools. It is possible to write so called *procedural macros* which let you add custom attributes to your functions, e.g. `#[rule_decorator] fn foo() { ... }`. With proc macros, you can do almost anything.

**However**, using proc macros for this is way too over-engineered (in my opinion). In your case, I would simply list all functions to be included in your vector:

```rust
fn test_constraint1(arg: u32) -> bool {
    arg < 29_500
} 
fn test_constraint2(arg: u32) -> bool {
    arg < 35_000
}

fn main() {
    let rules = vec![test_constraint1 as fn(_) -> _, test_constraint2];

    // Or, if you already have a vector and need to add to it:
    let mut rules = Vec::new();
    rules.extend_from_slice(
        &[test_constraint1 as fn(_) -> _, test_constraint2]
    );
}
```

A few notes about this code:

- I replaced `&Arg` with `u32`, because it doesn't have anything to do with the problem. Please omit unnecessary details from questions on StackOverflow.
- I used `_` in the number literals to increase readability.
- The strange `as fn(_) -> _` cast is sadly necessary. You can read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895946/expected-fn-item-found-a-different-fn-item-when-working-with-function-pointer).

Comment: I don't think that procedural macros would even work here, as there's no way for them to "build up" a vector across the separate invocations. You'd have to wrap the *entire file* in the macro for it to work, I believe. See also [Jan Hudec's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663699/how-to-include-a-list-of-functions-from-another-module-with-decorator#comment98016861_55663699), which mentions the current hack.

Comment: WDYTA duplicate of [How to introspect all available methods & members in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39266001/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Good point about proc macros. I guess it would be possible with dirty hacks, but yeah, I agree. About duplicate: it doesn't fit perfectly (as this question has a specific goal: creating a vector of function pointers), but I wouldn't mind closing this as dupe.